# How to make this animated navigation bar responsive?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, navbar

I have an animated navigation bar that I would like to have change from horizontal layout to vertical layout on narrow screens.

I tried to add images, but the post kept insisting I had incorrectly formatted code, so I just copied and pasted the code that I had. the first section is the nav bar html, the second section in the nav bar CSS, the third section is the media query css.

I have tried setting media queries and float to none.

```css
  nav {
  margin: 27px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 495px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #7dabd9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 110px;
}

a:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}

a:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
}

a:nth-child(5) {
  width: 120px;
}

nav .start-home,
a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

nav .start-about,
a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 110px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

nav .start-blog,
a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 210px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

nav .start-portefolio,
a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 160px;
  left: 310px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

nav .start-contact,
a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 120px;
  left: 470px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

'     
 main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  background-color: #7dabd9;
  float: none;
  width: 100vw;
  clear: both;
}

aside {
  float: none;
  width: 100vw;
}


}
@media screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:799px) {
  header,
  footer {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: black;
    background-color: #7dabd9;
    float: none;
    width: 100vw;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  aside {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:499px) {
    header,
    footer {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    main {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: black;
      background-color: #7dabd9;
      float: none;
      width: 90vw;
      clear: both;
    }
    aside {
      display: none;
      float: none;
      width: 90vw;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The `flex-direction` property allows you to switch easily between horizontal and vertical layout. For narrow screens, vary the `top` of your animated hover element, and for wide screens, vary its `left`.

```css
nav {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #7dabd9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 420px;
  }
}

nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav a {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.animation {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .animation {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

a:hover~.animation {
  height: 50px;
}

a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  top: 0;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  top: 150px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {

  a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 80px;
  }

  a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 110px;
  }

  a:nth-child(3) {
    width: 110px;
  }

  a:nth-child(4) {
    width: 120px;
  }

  a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 80px;
    left: 0;
  }

  a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    top: 0;
    width: 110px;
    left: 80px;
  }

  a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    top: 0;
    width: 110px;
    left: 190px;
  }

  a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    top: 0;
    width: 120px;
    left: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  <div class="animation"></div>
</nav>
```

After running this snippet, use the **full page** link to test the responsiveness.